# lerping glitches camera in react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm making a simple program that lets the user smoothly transition the camera to a set position whenever they press a button.
I'm trying to follow [this code](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/505#discussioncomment-2947270) and the transition works. But the camera glitches right a the beginning of the transition.
I suspect it has to do with state property correctly in calling useFrame but I don't know how to fix it.
Here's my current code:

```
function CameraAnimation(props) {
  useFrame(state => {
    if (props.started) {
      state.camera.lookAt(0, 2, 0);
      state.camera.position.lerp(new THREE.Vector3(6, 6, -4), .02);
    };
  })

  return null;
}

function App() {
  const [started, setStarted] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Canvas>
        <mesh>
          <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
        </mesh>
        <OrbitControls />
        <CameraAnimation started={started} />
      </Canvas>
      <button onClick={() => setStarted(!started)}>transition</button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

Comment: The camera is probably not looking at `0, 2, 0` until you start the animation. So when `started` becomes true, the angle of the camera jumps up suddenly.

Comment: Ah ok. Do you know how I could transition the lookAt smoothly as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you or not, but you can lerp the lookAt easily with something like this for exemple:

```
const lookAtInitial = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
const lookAtTo = new THREE.Vector3(3,1,10);

camera.lookAt(lookAtInitial.lerp(lookAtTo, 0.03));
```